# Let $G$ a simple group. Suppose exists a conjugacy class $C$ in $G$ such that $C \neq\{e\}$ is finite. Prove $G$ is finite.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, orbit-stabilizer

So I am pretty sure my proof lacks something because I never used the fact G is simple, and I would love some help.

So this is my proof:

Let's observe the action $G \mapsto C$ by conjugation. So, $\forall g \in G$ we have $g.c = gcg^{-1}$.

Let $c_1 \in C$, and we can notice that $|Oc_1|$ is actually the size of the conjugacy class of $c_1$, because the orbit of $c_1$ is all the objects in $C$ that $c_1$ can move to using conjugation under $G$. Thus implementing $|Oc_1|=|C|$.

From the datum $C$ is final we can deduce the orbit of $c_1$ is final.

It is given $C \neq$ {e} and therefore exists $e \neq c_2 \in C$.

By invalidation suppose $e \in C$, so there exists $g \in G$ such that $gc_2g^{-1} = e \to gc_2 = g \to c_2 = e$ and that is a contradiction.

Thus implementing $e \notin C$. Therefore we have $\forall c \in C$ we have $G_C$, the stabilizer of $C$ is also finite. Thus implementing $\forall c \in C$ we have $|G_C||O_c|$ is finite and by the orbit-stabilizer theorem we have $G$ is finite.

Comment: Your proof makes no sense. What do you mean by the stabilizer of a conjugacy class here, and how did you deduce it is finite? The statement is clearly false without the assumption that $G$ is simple. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}$ every conjugacy class is finite.

Comment: @Mark my deduction that it is finite came from the fact that it is given the conjugacy class is finite. If you could provide me with better proof I would very much appreciate it since i have been breaking my head over this for the past couple days.

Comment: You defined an action. As you probably know, every action induces a certain homomorphism. Since $G$ is simple, this homomorphism must be either trivial or injective. Try to continue from here.

Comment: @Mark Im having somewhat trouble defining this homomorphism. Say $\phi: G \to C$ is given by $\phi(g) \mapsto gcg^-1$ the $c \in C$ is constant so which one do i chose? A random one i can assume is different than e? Also i know i want to find the kernel of $\phi$ (so i can use first iso theorem) but i am not sure how $e \in C$ is defined.

Comment: $C$ is not a group, so you can't define a homomorphism to $C$. Any action of $G$ on a set $X$ induces a homomorphism $\varphi:G\to S_X$ (where $S_X$ is the group of permutations on $X$) by $\varphi(g)(x)=g.x$. If you don't know that then it's probably too early to try solving this exercise. (I don't know where you took it from)

Comment: @Mark I'm taking a course in group-theory, but it is obligatory as I'm actually studying computer science. I get mixed up with many of the definitions unfortunately, but you made a lot of order. How would i continue from here?

Comment: What you have is not a proof. You concluded $G_C$ is finite with no justification given, and you will not be able to find any, as Mark's example of $\Bbb Z$ shows. (And I assume you mean for $G_C$ to be interpreted as $G_c$, but this is not conventional notation because there is a difference between the pointwise and setwise stabilizer of a set, neither of which match the point-stabilizer of a particular element of a set in general.) Once you have a homomorphism $\phi:G\to S_X$, remember the first isomorphism theorem, kernels are normal subgroups, and note $S_X$ is finite.

Comment: @AsiMathStudent Try to think about it. I gave you a big hint. $\varphi$ is either trivial or injective, now try to prove the claim in each of the two cases. If it is injective, that's almost immediate. If it's trivial, a bit of work has to be done, but still not too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is heavily inspired by Mark's comments.
Its simple to verify that the map $\phi_g:C\to C, c\to gcg^{-1} $  its bijective i.e. $\phi_g\in S_C$, hence we can define homomorphism: $$F:G\to S_C, g\to \phi_g \;\;\;(\text{verify that this is really a homomorphism}). $$
Now $ker F\unlhd G$ and because G is simple we get that $ker F\in\{\{e\},G\}$.

**1)$ker F=\{e\}$** : By the first [isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems) we get: $$G\cong G/\{e\}\cong F(G)\le S_C \implies |G|\le|S_C|<\infty .$$

**2)$ker F=G$** : In this case $\phi_g=Id$ for every $g\in G$ hence: $$c=\phi_g(c)=gcg^{-1}\;\; \forall c\in C, g\in G$$ therefore $|C|=1$ (because $C$ its a Conjugacy class of some element $c_0$ but $gc_0g^{-1}=c_0$ everytime  so $C=\{c_0\}$) and $c_0\in Z(G)$ hence $<c_0>\unlhd G\stackrel{C\neq\{e\}}{\implies} G=<c_0>$  (because $G$ its simple). Now  $<c_0>$ must be finite, if not we have that $$ \{0\}\subsetneq <c_0^2>\subsetneq <c_0>=G $$ $$\text{because if }\; c_0=c_0^{2k}\implies c_0^{2k-1}=e\implies <c_0>=G \text{ finite}.$$ But now we have a proper, non trivial, normal subgroup of G and it's in contraddiction with simple assumption.

Comment: Thank you so much super clear proof!

Comment: For the last two lines, another way to state: since $G=\langle c_0 \rangle$, if $G$ is infinite, then $G\cong \mathbb{Z}$, and every $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a proper normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, hence contradiction with simple group.

Comment: yes, that's clearer argument.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ acts transitively by conjugation on $C$. Since $G$ is simple, the action is faithful. Therefore, $G$ embeds into $S_C$, which is finite because $C$ is finite. So, $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

The proof goes as follows.

Let $G$ be a simple group with a non-trivial finite conjugacy class $C$. In consequence, $\exists x \in C$ such that $x \neq e$. Its centralizer $C_G(x)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. As $G$ is simple, its normal subgroups can only be the trivial group $\{e\}$ or $G$ itself.

If $C_G(x) = \{e\}$, the orbit-stabilizer theorem leads straightforwardly to the desired result; indeed, we get :
$$
|C| = [G:C_G(x)] = \frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|} = |G| \quad\Longrightarrow\quad |G| = |C| < \infty.
$$

The case $C_G(x) = G$ is a bit more complicated. Indeed, in that case, the center of $G$ is not trivial, since $x \in Z(G) \lhd G$. If $Z(G) \neq G$, then $G$ is not simple anymore and the proof is finished *ab absurdo*. If $Z(G) = G$, then $G$ is abelian and thus not simple as before, unless $G$ is a prime-order cyclic group, hence finiteness.

Comment: Why is the centralizer normal?

Comment: It is due to the isomorphism theorem; actually, the centralizer corresponds to the kernel of the homomorphism in Bongo's answer $-$ and you can check straightforwardly that homomorphism kernels always constitute normal subgroups.